# How can request be both from an EC2 instance and from clients machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2, request

For example, a request has the request header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 ... AppleWebKit/... Chrome/... Safari/537.36' AND the request header 'Origin: http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx' where the former is the user agent for the clients browser and the latter is the ip address for the EC2 instance. I retrieve this information via chrome dev tools, the request appears when I load the page in.

For more context, the front end server is daemon on the EC2 (when the site is loaded a request is made to an nginx proxy, and then to the front end server). Then in the front end code an api call is made to the search server (meilisearch), which is also a daemon running on the EC2.

This is where it gets tricky because if the request is made from the client's machine (because of the UA header), why would the ip address not be the same as the clients' machine? Apologies if this question sounds dumb, thank you in advance for your insights.

Comment: Where are you 'receiving' this request? Can you tell us more about the situation... for example, did a person on a computer on the Internet access a web server on an Amazon EC2 instance and you retrieved this information from the web server's log? Please Edit your question and tell us more.

Comment: Not 100% clear what your scenario is but if an intermediate proxy is forwarding a request then it's common for the source IP of the forwarded request to be that of the proxy and an [x-forwarded-for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) HTTP header will be injected to identify the originating client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood the meaning of the [`Origin`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7.2) header.

> When included in an HTTP request, the Origin header field indicates
> the origin(s) that "caused" the user agent to issue the request.

So it's not the IP address of the "clients' machine", it's the host that served the page that led to the request being made. What you're seeing is exactly what you'd expect.